# Get current domain in ASMX

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

In C# in an asmx web service how do I get the current domain that the webservice was called on?
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host returns kindof what I want but instead of http://mydomain.com/Folder/Mywebservice.asmx I just need http://mydomain.com.
I know i could just cut that string up but it seems really in-elegant.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of the link below - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817/whats-the-best-method-in-asp-net-to-obtain-the-current-domain You will get answer here.

Answer (score 7):

[`Uri.GetLeftPart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx) helps here:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

Answer (score 3):

In VB.Net I have used...

```
With HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
    sDomain=.Scheme & System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter & .Host
End With
```

Or if you care about the Port then...

```
With HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
    sDomain=.Scheme & System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter & .Host & IIf(.IsDefaultPort,"",":") & .Port
End With
```

Should be easy to convert to C# ;)