# https on proxy server for asp.net web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, networking

I have simple asp.net webservice has login method and its deployed on IIS server url is `http://sitename.domain.org:9111/membership/membershipdir.asmx`.

My network team created a SSL proxy url on proxy server (i think it is apache) for this web service site.Now webservice can access through proxy like this `https://www.domain.org/webservices/spws/Membership/membershipdir.asmx`.

It works fine but when I invoke the webservice method. the result window url showing on `http://servername.domain.org:9111/Membership/membershipdir.asmx/Login`

Now network team complaining  the port 9111 still exposes to public for the login portion. something has to change in application. I am not understanding what should I change in application level.

I am also not understanding why results on showing with server name without proxy name?

Anybody have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: [What's the best method in ASP.NET to obtain the current domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817/whats-the-best-method-in-asp-net-to-obtain-the-current-domain) to always use the same domain the user made the initial request to.

Now, I'm not sure about the proxy server situation... if the proxy server is making any changes, it should be doing the opposite on the way back out... so I really can't speak to that problem... but, regardless, make sure you are using the original request domain by either using relative paths, or by the method in the Question linked to above.

Comment: My question is when request goes through proxy url than response should come through proxy url only right?. Why response it self coming through regurlar url?

Comment: @James123  I don't think your response is coming through regular url while request goes thru proxy. Most probably, your request also goes thru regular url.