# Request.Url.Authority doesn't return expected domain

Tags: asp.net

I'm generating an e-mail in my website's controller with a link to my website:

```
"http://" & Request.Url.Authority & "/some-page"
```

This works when I tested it on my local machine (returns `localhost:12345`) and in production (returns `www.company.com`) but 1 person got this as a result:

```
http://www.company..com/some-page
```

As you can see there are 2 `..` in the domain name. I can't reproduce this error, how is this possible?

Edit: a bit more information

- The type of email I'm sending is a plain text email (no HTML or RTF)
- The webserver logs show www.company.com as the domain when the problematic request was made
- I only received a partial screenshot of the email. I think the email client is Outlook but I see no reason why Outlook would have misinterpreted the link.
- It's certainly possible that this person (or malware) has edited the content of this email.

Comment: Can you add some logging and see what `Request.Url` contains when this happens?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know the email client that received the message. Perhaps look into the source of the message to verify what actually got sent - maybe email client misinterpreted the link.

Comment: Any change the person did it when he or she was cut and pasting it somewhere?

Comment: What happens when you visit http://www.company..com/some-page?  Is it possible to get fiddler logs at the point this occurs?

Comment: @m.edmondson The browser gives a server not found error. Fiddler wouldn't log anything.

Comment: @ZippyV - It would log the request

Comment: @m.edmondson Fiddler gives a `502 Fiddler - DNS Lookup Failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a problem with how the email is being encoded, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603002/186288. In summary, you should change the encoding to UTF8 to force base-64 encoding of the email, otherwise some email clients can misinterpret the default Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-Printable; encoding and add in extra "."s in URLs that happen to hit a wrap point.

To do this, add this line before you send the email:

```
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Answer (score 2):

I should have tried this sooner with a simple example:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim SomeAddress As New Uri("http://www.example..com/test")

        Console.WriteLine(SomeAddress.Authority)
    End Sub
End Module
```

This will throw an exception in the constructor:

> System.UriFormatException - Invalid URI: The hostname could not be
>   parsed

So the customer couldn't have received such an email from my code without editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `Request.Url.Authority`? I suggest you avoid to use it, and use Request.Url.Host. It's better to use `Request.Url.Host` or Uri class constructor, when consturcting incorrect URI it will throw exception and you can either log it or show error.

Anyway it's hard to predict why one user have got `www.company..com` Anyway your code with `Request.Url.Authority` concatenation can not produce it. So maybe error is in other location.

Comment: This information is incorrect. `Authority` simply returns the `Host` and `Port` (e.g., `localhost:12345`) of the original URI. It does not perform any DNS lookup.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Look in documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx. Gets the Domain Name System (DNS) host name or IP address and the port number for a server. For your example based on what in DNS it will return localhost:12345 or 127.0.0.1:12345

Comment: That description in MSDN Library is misleading. As the **Property Value** and **Remarks** sections make clear, a better description would be "Gets the DNS host name or IP address and (if present) the port number components of the URI represented by this instance." Or just go [straight to the source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Net/System/URI@cs/9/URI@cs).

Comment: -1 as based on Michael Liu addition and link to source code just above  the answer is incorrect and misleading. @Regfor may be worth amending the answer.

Comment: One small doubt. if I run the application in localhost I have port number in my URL but in production I do not have port number in the URL. So, I can freely use Url.Authority right? I mean if port number is not there then URl.Authority will act same as URL.Host right. I mean I will still be able to get the URL correctly right? please guide me,.