# Get real url address that user typed in address bar in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some domains that has been bound in IIS to one application.
for example

```
somesite.com
somesite2.com
somesite3.com
```

Bind to Application1.

When I call Request.RawUrl it returns a different address to compare what user has been typed in address bar.

How can I get real entered url

Comment: What do you mean by real address? What does the user enter in his browser and what do you get in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RawUrl only contains the server path, without the domain, which seems to be the most interesting part for you.

In that case, it seems like a duplicate of [What's the best method in ASP.NET to obtain the current domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817/whats-the-best-method-in-asp-net-to-obtain-the-current-domain)

Here the solution was to use

```
Request.Url.Host
```