# How to substract current url in C#?

Tags: c#, url

I want to get root url?

```
@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

This is example if i have somthing like this

http://www.example.com/contact if I am  on page contact page
I want to get this like http://www.example.com is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817/whats-the-best-method-in-asp-net-to-obtain-the-current-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get base URl use

```
Request.Url.Authority
```