# Dynamic WebAPI Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following code to get data from my api:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:58639/api/cars/" + carId + "?includeOwners=true";

        var model = client
            .GetAsync(url)
            .Result
            .Content.ReadAsAsync<Car[]>().Result;
        Car c = model[0];
        newCount = c.Persons.Count;

        /* More Code */
    }
}
```

using this route in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Is there a way to create the URL dynamically such that if the site was hosted somewhere other than localhost this would still work?  I have attempted to do this with Url.RouteUrl and UrlHelper, yet I can't find a way to include the "?includeOwners=true" filter with them.

Comment: Do you need something like: `Url.Content("~/api/cars/")`?

Comment: Apparently my Url doesn't have a Content() method...  What library are you getting Url from?

Comment: It is written that way in Razor. Probably you can write UrlHelper.Content? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: In what context does this code run, is it an ASP.NET MVC controller or WebForms page? In that case see [What's the best method in ASP.NET to obtain the current domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817/whats-the-best-method-in-asp-net-to-obtain-the-current-domain).

Comment: This code is in a SignalR hub method

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the server part in a config file (web.config etc) and read it from there when you're constructing the url.

Just add the base url part in an appSetting and read it using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameOfKey"]`

Answer (score -2):

Please try the below code:

`string domainName = ((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];`

you can dynamically load the Host and Port or the whole domainname.

Comment: Please improve your _"try this"_ answer by explaining what the code you provided does.