# How to get current domain name in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the current domain name in asp.net c#.

I am using this code.

```
string DomainName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

My URL is `localhost:5858`but it's returning only `localhost`.

Now, I am using my project in localhost. I want to get localhost:5858.

For another example, when I am using this domain

```
www.somedomainname.com
```

I want to get `somedomainname.com`

Please give me an idea how to get the current domain name.

Comment: Hostname and domain name are 2 different things.  Are you wanting a domain that is mapped to your specific IP address, or the hostname of the machine on which it runs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method in ASP.NET to obtain the current domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817/whats-the-best-method-in-asp-net-to-obtain-the-current-domain)

Comment: var base_url = "@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Content("~/")"

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Using `Request.Url.Host` is appropriate - it's how you retrieve the value of the HTTP `Host:` header, which specifies which hostname (domain name) the UA (browser) wants, as the Resource-path part of the HTTP request does not include the hostname.

Note that `localhost:5858` is not a domain name, it is an endpoint specifier, also known as an "authority", which includes the hostname and TCP port number. This is retrieved by accessing `Request.Uri.Authority`.

Furthermore, it is not valid to get `somedomain.com` from `www.somedomain.com` because a webserver could be configured to serve a different site for `www.somedomain.com` compared to `somedomain.com`, however if you are sure this is valid in your case then you'll need to manually parse the hostname, though using `String.Split('.')` works in a pinch.

Note that webserver (IIS) configuration is distinct from ASP.NET's configuration, and that ASP.NET is actually completely ignorant of the HTTP binding configuration of the websites and web-applications that it runs under. The fact that both IIS and ASP.NET share the same configuration files (`web.config`) is a red-herring.

Answer (score 172):

Try getting the “left part” of the url, like this:

```
string domainName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

This will give you either `http://localhost:5858` or `https://www.somedomainname.com` whether you're on local or production. If you want to drop the `www` part, you should configure IIS to do so, but that's another topic.

Do note that the resulting URL will not have a trailing slash.

Comment: This worked superbly for my needs. One small correction, however: when requesting the Authority part, the returned string will not include the trailing path delimiter. Thus: `http://localhost:60333`

Comment: var base_url = "@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Content("~/")"

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on Asp.Net Core 2.2. I'm getting 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no accessible extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: @Stian Apparently there's another post already answering that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core . This answers focus only on the URI part.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host only returns localhost, not the port, this is the best answer.

Comment: Request is not available when there is no request e.g. in application startup methods, static class initializers ...

Comment: As @Stian wrote, this doesn't work in dotnet core latest version HttpRequest no longer contains any property called Url...

Comment: @BrianBirtle This answer is about the GetLefPart() method on any Uri object. If you need an HttpContext, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 63):

Here is a screenshot of `Request.RequestUri` and all its properties for everyone's reference.

[image]

Comment: Do the same thing when your breakpoint is in Global.Application_Start. Request object doesn't exist at that time!

Answer (score 20):

You can try the following code :

```
 Request.Url.Host +
    (Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port)
```

Answer (score 12):

I use it like this in asp.net core 3.1

```
 var url =Request.Scheme+"://"+ Request.Host.Value;
```

Answer (score 6):

`www.somedomain.com` *is* the domain/host. The subdomain is an important part. `www.` is often used interchangeably with not having one, but that has to be set up as a rule (even if it's set by default) because they are not equivalent. Think of another subdomain, like `mx.`. That probably has a different target than `www.`.

Given that, I'd advise not doing this sort of thing. That said, since you're asking I imagine you have a good reason.

Personally, I'd suggest special-casing `www.` for this.

```
string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.HostAndPort, UriFormat.Unescaped);;

if (host.StartsWith("www."))
    return host.Substring(4);
else
    return host;
```

Otherwise, if you're really 100% sure that you want to chop off *any* subdomain, you'll need something a tad more complicated.

```
string host = ...;

int lastDot = host.LastIndexOf('.');

int secondToLastDot = host.Substring(0, lastDot).LastIndexOf('.');

if (secondToLastDot > -1)
    return host.Substring(secondToLastDot + 1);
else
    return host;
```

Getting the port is just like other people have said.

Comment: Unfortunately your last function doesn't work for http://sub.domain.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host is returning the correct values. If you run it on www.somedomainname.com it will give you www.somedomainname.com. If you want to get the 5858 as well you need to use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port
```

Answer (score 1):

the `Request.ServerVariables` object works for me. I don't know of any reason not to use it.

`ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]` and `ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"]` should get what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to get fully qualified domain name:

```
Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick easy way to just get the name of the url.

```
            var urlHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;

            var xUrlHost = urlHost.Split('.');
            foreach(var thing in xUrlHost)
            {
                if(thing != "www" && thing != "com")
                {
                    urlHost = thing;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get base URL in MVC even with subdomain `www.somedomain.com/subdomain`:

```
var url = $"{Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}{Url.Content("~/")}";
```

Answer (score 0):

**string domainName = HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;**

this line should solve it

Answer (score 0):

in dot net 8 you can put this anywhere in your controller and use it (based on some of the code here)

```
protected string GetAuthorityFromRequestUrl()
{
    var requestFullUrl = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl());
    return requestFullUrl.Authority;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)

Comment: This answer doesn't elaborate on why this works, and in fact, is identical to one of the existing answers.