# Create one Nuget Package for both ASP.NET 4 & ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

We have a library which works in ASP.NET 4 and uses `HttpContext.Current`. We are aware that we [can't use `HttpContext.Current` in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/httpcontext-current-in-asp-net-vnext) but should use `IHttpContextAccessor`.

How can we change this library so we **both** support ASP.NET 4 (by using `HttpContext.Current`) and ASP.NET Core (`IHttpContextAccessor`) and packaged as **one** NuGet package?

Comment: Why not refactor the library not to depend on either? If you need something from the web assembly, then inject it in.

Comment: @Aristos IHttpContextAccessor isn't there in ASP.NET 4

Comment: @manson there is no DI in ASP.NET 4 yet (out of the box).

Comment: Yes, OK, you have right.

Comment: Are you using the new "Class Library (Package)" project type? This one is meant for .NET and packages for multiple. Depending on the TFM (Target framework moniker) you setup, it will create libraries for these platforms. You then use compiler preconditions for platform specific code. It's still two libraries/packages, but they will be compiled and packaged by Visual Studio on build, so this work doesn't have to be done manually or via build scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it isn't possible. The same that you can't create a one NuGet package to target both MVC1 and MVC2 (both not as Nuget package available)

Of course you could use assembly bindings, but only when there aren't breaking changes.

Microsoft is naming there ASP.NET Core packages with "AspNetCore", e.g. [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) vs [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

Create three libraries.

1. Uses HttpContext
2. Uses IHttpContextAccessor
3. Factory which loads from one of these library.

1 and 2 have the same assembly name and Factory just references either of the two.

At a time there will be only two assemblies present as reference in the folder. Factory and one among the other two in references.

Create a nuget package with all the three assemblies. 1 and 2 go in separate folders lets call it aspnet4 and aspnet5.

Package also contains target file which is used by aspnet projects. The target file copies factory and one of the libraries into the references folder depending upon a property present in aspnet project. This property could be something like aspnet=aspnet5.

This might be a too big thing and simpler solution might exist. I will think of a simpler solution.

#### Sample Code

```
//4. AspNetUsageBaseClass Assembly
namespace AspNetUsage
{
    //rest of code

    public abstract AspNetUsageBaseClass
    {
        //rest of code
        public abstract void HttpContextIHttpContextAccessor();
    }
}

//1. AspNetUsage Assembly, Reference AspNetUsageBaseClass Assembly
using AspNetUsage;
public class AspNetUsage:AspNetUsageBaseClass
{
    public override void HttpContextIHttpContextAccessor()
    {
        //HttpContext based code
    }
}

//2. AspNetUsage Assembly, Reference AspNetUsageBaseClass Assembly
using AspNetUsage;
public class AspNetUsage:AspNetUsageBaseClass
{
    public override void HttpContextIHttpContextAccessor()
    {
        //IHttpContextAccessor based code
    }
}
```

Now there will be in total 3 assemblies. One base class assembly. Two others implementing specific functionality.
Inside nuget package structure should be:

`AspNetUsageBaseClass.dll` - base class assembly

`AspNet4\AspNetUsage.dll` - HttpContext assembly

`AspNet5OrCore\AspNetUsage.dll` - IHttpContextAccessor assembly

`AspNet.target` - This will be imported in asp net project and depending on the value of the property extract one of the two dlls.

Inside AspNet project you would have:

```
AspNetUsageBaseClass context = new AspNetUsage();
context.HttpContextIHttpContextAccessor();
```

This is not `Factory` pattern based but this can be extended to `Factory` pattern based with some modification.

There might be some mistakes as I have used notepad to type the logic in absence of VS.

Comment: Could you give a code example for step 3: "Factory which loads from one of these library"?

Comment: While working through the code I realized, Factory pattern can be avoided here. You just need the two different assemblies (off course with the same name and type) each using respective HttpContext. Rest of the things like nuget package remain same. I'm in the middle of writing the code using the factory.

Comment: Do you have an example of AspNet.target? And this file is in the root of the nupkg?

Comment: Open any c# project in notepad. There you will find it. You can build upon that.

Answer (score 0):

If you define two target frameworks in `project.json` (like `aspnetcore` and `net451`), then two separate dlls will be created and put into `lib/aspnetcore` and `lib/net451` inside the nuget package. Nuget will know which one to use, based on the target framework of the project that consumes the package.

Now, you can use `#ifdef` statements in your library to distinguish, which parts of code should be compiled only for specified platforms.

A simple example:

```
using System;

namespace MyLib
{
#if NETFX
    using HttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext;
#elif NETCORE
    using HttpContext = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext;
#endif
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string GetUserAgent(HttpContext ctx)
        {
            return ctx.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
        }
        public void WriteToResponse(HttpContext ctx, string text)
        {
#if NETFX
            ctx.Response.Output.Write(text);
#elif NETCORE
            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            ctx.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

To make these switches work, you have to define framework-specific constants in project.json:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [
          "NETCORE"
        ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.0.0"
      }
    },
    "net451": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [
          "NETFX"
        ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
```

Note that both frameworks have different set of dependencies. `HttpContext` here will be a different type when compiled for netcoreapp and for net451. Fortunatelly, these types have very similar methods, so often times you can use them in the same way, without `#ifdef`s (like in `GetUserAgent`). Other times, you won't be able to avoid it (like in `WriteToResponse`).

Now, in a AspNet Core project you could use this library like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) => {
            var lib = new MyLib.MyClass();
            var msg = lib.GetUserAgent(ctx);
            lib.WriteToResponse(ctx, "user agent is: " + msg);
        });
    }
```

And in old AspNet MVC:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var lib = new MyLib.MyClass();
        var msg = lib.GetUserAgent(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
        lib.WriteToResponse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, "user agent is: " + msg);
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
}
```

*Full source code on [github](https://github.com/heavymetaldev/dotnetcore-varia/tree/master/httplib)*.

Comment: Too bad this won't work as you could run asp.net core also on net451.

Comment: @Julian: in that case, add `dnx451` framework (yes, it still works with `dotnet`) to the library and use it in asp.net core app instead of `net451`. This has the same meaining of "use full .Net 451 framework", but doesn't cause collision. (I've also updated the source code).