# How to access the Session in ASP.NET Core via static variable?

Tags: session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In earlier version of Asp.Net session can be accessed in any page like a static variable using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]
```

In Asp.Net Core, How to access session in different class called via controller, without passing the session property as an  additional parameter in the constructor of all classes

Comment: How about reading the docs? It's very well described at this stage of ASP.NET Core: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html#installing-and-configuring-session

Comment: in all the samples i saw in that site, i can see only "HttpContext objContext" object passed as a parameter to the method / delegate, and session is accessed as  objContext.Session. I thought like someway will be available like earlier Asp.Net , something  like HttpContext.Current.Session , so that passing an extra parameter can be avoided

Comment: Inside a controller you have access to HttpContext (if controller derives from `Controller` base class) otherwise you have to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

***Revised approach 1/17/17 to fix bug***

First, I'll assume that you have your ASP.NET Core application configured to use session state.  If not see @slfan's answer [How to access the Session in ASP.NET Core via static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785767/how-to-access-the-session#answer-37799060)

> How to access session in different class called via controller, without passing the session property as an additional parameter in the constructor of all classes

Asp.Net Core is designed around dependency injection and in general the designers didn't provide much static access to context information.  More specifically there is no equivalent to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`.

In Controllers you can get access to Session vars via `this.HttpContext.Session` but you specifically asked how to get access to the session from methods called by the controller **without** passing the session property as a parameter.

So, to do this we need to setup our own static class to provide access to session and we need some code to initialize that class at startup.  Since it's likely that a person may want static access to the whole `HttpContext` object and not just the `Session` I took that approach.

So first we need the static class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; 
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace App.Web {

    public static class AppHttpContext {
        static IServiceProvider services = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides static access to the framework's services provider
        /// </summary>
        public static IServiceProvider Services {
            get { return services; }
            set {
                if(services != null) {
                    throw new Exception("Can't set once a value has already been set.");
                }
                services = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides static access to the current HttpContext
        /// </summary>
        public static HttpContext Current {
            get {
                IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor = services.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;
                return httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext;
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Next we need to add a service to the DI container that can provide access to the current `HttpContext`.  This service ships with the Core MVC framework but is not installed by default.  So we need to "install" it with a single line of code. This line goes in the `ConfigureServices` method of the Startup.cs file and can be located anywhere in that method:

```
//Add service for accessing current HttpContext
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Next we need to setup our static class so that it has access to the DI container to obtain the service we just installed.  The code below goes in the `Configure` method of the Startup.cs file.  This line can be be located anywhere in that method:

```
AppHttpContext.Services = app.ApplicationServices;
```

Now any method called by the `Controller`, even via the async await pattern, can access the current `HttpContext` via `AppHttpContext.Current`

So, if we use the `Session` extension methods in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace, we can save an `int` called "Count" to session could be done like this:

```
AppHttpContext.Current.Session.SetInt32("Count", count);
```

And retrieving an `int` called "Count" from session could be done like this:

```
int count count = AppHttpContext.Current.Session.GetInt32("Count");
```

Enjoy.

Comment: @ Ron C Great answer. A notice to others, replace `await next();` with `await next.Invoke();` in **Core 1.0**

Comment: This is one of the most sensible answers I have seen regarding "global session access solution". Does this approach have some drawbacks when compared to dependency injection approach? I'v been trying to figure out how I should implement access to "app-specific configuration variables" (read: "env variables", user/thread/httpContext-specific) and most examples are using depency injection approach. I'm bit hesitant on having the need to add httpContext as param for every constructor when accessing form controllers, as it's possible that some methods may end up being static.

Answer (score 4):

In Startup.ConfigureServices you have to add the service

```
services.AddSession();
```

and in the method Configure you have to use it (important: call before `app.UseMvc()`)

```
app.UseSession();
```

Now you can use it in your controllers (if derived from Controller). You can store

```
var data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
HttpContext.Session.Set("key", data); // store byte array

byte[] readData;
HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("key", out readData); // read from session
```

When you import the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` then you can use `SetString` and `SetInt32` as well.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

HttpContext.Session.SetString("test", "data as string"); // store string
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("number", 4711); // store int

int ? number = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("number");
```

Outside the controller you do not have access to the HttpContext, but you can inject an `IHttpContextAccessor` instance like described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-httpcontext-current)

Comment: What should I do if I don't know the size that data byte[] should be?

Comment: @user8128167 what do you mean with you don't know the size of the byte array? In .NET the size of a data array is always known. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I mean if I'm going to call "HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("key", out data);" then shouldn't I know the size in bytes that data is going to need to be to get the value out of session based on "key"?

Comment: @user8128167 No, as 'data' is an out parameter, the byte array will be allocated. It would be rather stupid if you had to know the size of the stored data beforehand. You normally read the Session date in a different controller/action.

Comment: Good point, I totally missed that "out" keyword so thanks.  Perhaps your answer would be more clear if you put var data = new byte[] {}; instead of "var data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };"?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store and retrieve a complex object from Session, you could instead use these extensions:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var data = session.GetString(key);  
        if (data == null)  
        {  
            return default(T);  
        }  
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
    }
}
```

Then you would call them like this:

```
User user = new User();  
user.Name = "Jignesh Trivedi";  
user.Percentage = 75.45;             

HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("UserData", user);
```

Or,

```
ViewBag.data = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<User>("UserData");
```

For details, please see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/session-state-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

If you see this, congratulations, you have found the secret solution to the problem that was asked 7 years ago (at the date of writing this).

There is an nuget package that adds the functionality you are looking for. The link is:

[GitHub project repository](https://github.com/dotnet/systemweb-adapters/tree/main)

The instructions are in the page but in short, by adding this package and adding to lines to your program.cs file you can access the cookies and all other data in the Context via static methods.

Add the package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters

Below is example code of it working:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Added to enable SystemWeb
builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

// Added to enable SystemWeb
app.UseSystemWebAdapters();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

My static class

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static void Run() {

            string value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value;
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "Value1");

            Test.Run();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```