# Using a JWT sent by Angular to an Aspnet core 1.0 web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

I am migrating my older app written in (VS2013) MVC5 with Angular 1 to (VS2015) MVC 6 with Angular 2. In my MVC 5 app, I used to recieve a token from the client in a post action method on the Web UI side which I used to then store to session using the following lines of code :

```
 //Store token details
 [HttpPost]
 public void EvaluateToken(string token)
 {
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SecurityToken st = tokenHandler.ReadToken(token);
    var tokenData = ((JwtSecurityToken)st);
    var claims = tokenData.Claims.Where(t => t.Type.Equals(" ")).ToList();

    ClaimsIdentity cIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
    ci.AddClaims(claims);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, cIdentity );

    string user = "//get username from token";

    ClaimsPrincipal cPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal (cIdentity);

    //write to cookie
    SessionSecurityToken sst = new SessionSecurityToken(cPrincipal , TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
    sst.IsReferenceMode = true; 
    SessionAuthenticationModule ssm = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
    ssm.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sst);
 }
```

The code above works well for non-aspnetcore projects and I am able to retrieve the claims from the Authorization Context using the following lines of code where `action` contains the claim set on the attribute over the respective action method being called and `val` contains a bool true or false of the specified claim exists or not in the `context.Principal`.

```
public class CustomClaimsAuthorizationManager: ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{

    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var action = context.Action.First().Value;
        bool val= context.Principal.HasClaim(" ", action);
        return val;
    }
}
```

However, when moving to a core project, I get this error:

> ID1061: HttpContext.Current is null. This code path is only valid when
>   in the execution context of ASP.NET.

on this line of code in my EvaluateToken method:

```
SessionAuthenticationModule ssm = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
```

I need this line to work so that when I try to access an action method that has my custom claim attribute, I should be able to evaluate if the claim in the token exists or not. If there is no way to move this as-is to aspnet core, then I want to know how in aspnet core can I use a token to authorize access to a particular view having only the passed in token and the audience, issuer and secret key used to generate the token. The documentation specifies adding custom policies and seems to take a different path. I'm not sure how to use that kind of logic to store the claims in a principal object on the UI side so it can be used when moving between views on the UI side.

This is what I have in my startup.cs file on the aspnet core web project in the Configure method:

```
var issuer = "localhost";
var aud = "localhost";
var secret = "SecretValueHere";

var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret));

            var jwtBearerOptions = new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                Audience = aud ,
                ClaimsIssuer = issuer,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = aud ,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    RequireExpirationTime = true  
                }
            };

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ID1061: HttpContext.Current is null. This code path is only valid when
>   in the execution context of ASP.NET.

HttpContext.Current is not available in Aspnet Core. See [Access HttpContext.Current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-httpcontext-current) .

> I need this line to work so that when I try to access an action method
>   that has my custom claim attribute, I should be able to evaluate if
>   the claim in the token exists or not

You just need(i assume claims are stored in token):

1. JWT authentication middleware(you already tried it)
2. [Claims Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html#claims-based-authorization).

If you need additional claims not stored in token then you can use [Claims Transformation](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) or `OnTokenValidated` event of jwt authentication middleware.

Comment: I am using `ClaimsPrinciplePermission` attribute and not the `Authorize` attribute. Is there a way to do it with `ClaimsPrinciplePermission` in aspnet core? or do I have to move all that to Authorize?

Comment: Is there a special reason to use ClaimsPrinciplePermission for your case? If not i would use authorize attribute.

Comment: I am migrating legacy code over into aspnet core. There would be a lot of rework to do that. On a related note, I have tried what you mentioned, using this example here to do a login ( http://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authentication-with-asp-net-core/ ) and this example ( https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html ) to evaluate incoming claims. However, the list of claims in the `AuthorizationHandlerContext context` property yeilds no result. Why is this?

Comment: Make sure jwt bearer authentication works correctly and sets principal claims. You can look User.Claims to check. Also could you post code you try.