# How do you use 'HttpContext' class?

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

I'm having trouble using the HttpContext class.
I can access HttpContext but can't call it's functions.

I want to use HttpContext.Authentication inside a helper class I'm writing.

I can't write anything like this (see below) inside my helper class:

```
private void SignInUser()
{
... Code
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(..);
}
```

However, I can access HttpContext inside my controller class.

I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access HttpContext.Current](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-httpcontext-current)

Comment: Are you specifically trying to access user identity?

Comment: @trevorc I'm specifically trying to use the SignInAsync method inside of a helper class.

Comment: @DavidG Is this answer also relevant to asp.net core?  As in am I supposed to be using IHttpContextAccessor?  Why can I still use HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync in my controller class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create file HttpContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace System.Web
{
    public static class HttpContext
    {
        private static IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext Current => _contextAccessor.HttpContext;

        internal static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }
    }

    public static class StaticHttpContextExtensions
    {
        public static void AddHttpContextAccessor(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }

        public static IApplicationBuilder UseStaticHttpContext(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Configure(httpContextAccessor);
            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

Next in you startup file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
...
 services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
```

Finally for example out of controllers, if you need current user name

```
var currentUsername = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name)
            ? System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
            : "Anonymous";
```

I tested whit ASPNET Core 1.0 and 1.1

EDIT
Sorry i forgot in your startup file in section configure add this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
...
app.UseStaticHttpContext();
...
```

Comment: Okay awesome I'm about to implement this.  What if I was going to write a library to accomplish this same goal?  I ask because there isn't a startup file in a library.  I understand that you could obviously configure the startup file in the core app that the library is being used inside but what if I didn't want my users to have to do any configurations?  Or is this deserving of it's own separate queston?

Comment: For more information about HttpContext recommend [http://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/](http://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Great answer and reference.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't use static classes to store context or context accessor, this beats the idea of having a built-in dependency injection in the first place. IHttpContextAccessor should be injected in all classes which require it

Answer (score 3):

If you wannt to use a helper class which signs in a user, you should make an extension method instead, which either wraps around `IHttpContextAccessor` or `HttpContext` itself.

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions 
{
    public static void SignInUser(this HttpContext context)
    {
        await context.Authentication.SignInAsync(..);
    }

    public static void SignInUser(this.IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) 
    {
        // Calls the method from above
        contextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInUser();
    }
}
```

Or if you have a bigger dependency chain and require other injected services, convert it into a injectable class:

```
public class UserLogonService : IUserLogonService 
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public UserLogonService(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        if(contextAccessor==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));

        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public void SingInUser()
    {
        contextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInUser();
    }
}
```

and in `Startup.Configure` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IUserLogonService, UserLogonService>();
```

Now you can inject `IUserLogonService` everywhere in your project via constructor, i.e.

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IUserLogonService userLogon;

    public MyController(IUserLoggonService userLogon)
    {
        this.userLogon = userLogon;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        await userLogon.SignInUser();
    }
}
```

It's clean, decoupled and can easily be unit tested, which you can't do with a static helper class.