# System.Web.HttpContext in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, httpcontext, .net-standard

I'm developing a .NET Standard 2.0 class library in Visual Studio 2017 15.5 which at some point tries to call a Web Service.
The way to authenticate is by using WSE 3.0 (Microsoft.Web.Services3).

Before the call, it crashes executing this instruction:

```
UsernameToken userToken = new UsernameToken(sUser, sPass, PasswordOption.SendHashed);
```

The error is:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Does **System.Web.HttpContext** exist in .NET Standard? How can I solve this?

Comment: add a reference to System.Web. make sure you choose version 4.0

Comment: It doesn't appear in the assemblies list from the references' manager. I even tried to add the reference from the .dll file with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpContext in .net standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357689/httpcontext-in-net-standard-library)