# Is it possible to set and get value in session in .NET Standard project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, .net-standard

I need to set session variable in .NET Standard project and also get the value from same as well as .NET framework project. I am not able to see Httpcontext in .NET Standard. Also, I could not find any ways to use session in .net standard project.

How do I set session variable value in .NET Standard project and get its value in .NET Standard and .NETFramework project???

I found this URL:
[HttpContext in .net standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357689/httpcontext-in-net-standard-library)
Tried using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions but session only accepts byte[] type.

Comment: What kind of project do you write? A .net standard assembly that you want to use from web applications?

Comment: yes.. actually, business login is in .net standard and web application is in .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

A library for business logic directly accessing session state is no good architecture. Business logic code should not even care whether it runs in a web application or some other type of application.

Create a better abstraction. Declare an interface `ISession` in your library with all the methods that you want to use. Then provide a mechanism for an application that uses your library to provide an actual implementation of `ISession`.

In your web application, write a class that implements `ISession` by using the ASP.net session concept in the .net Framework.