# I am trying to access the session values in .CS file but getting error like this " 'HttpContext' does not contain definition for 'Current "

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-standard

I am trying to access the session values in .CS file but getting the following error:

> 'HttpContext' does not contain definition for 'Current'

This is my code:

form.aspx.cs

```
Session["from"] = lblMgrMailFrom.Text;
```

class.cs located in a .NET Standard library

```
string from = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["from"];
```

Comment: If you have access to a debugger, perhaps you could set a breakpoint and inspect the HttpContext to see what it does/doesn't contain.  That information may be helpful to you.

Comment: @trademark That is a compiler error, so debugging should not be possible.

Comment: Are you using .net core perhaps?

Comment: @Igor If it was .NET Core, they probably would not be on a page called form.aspx.cs, which is for Web Forms.

Comment: no i am not using .net core

Comment: We need more information here to be able to help you. Please be explicit about the framework you're using (Web Forms, ASP.NET etc) and describe where class.cs is. Is it in the same project as your web application, or a separate class library? Is it .NET Standard or .NET Framework etc?

Comment: @mason - I have seen users copy and paste code files from online into their projects hoping they would just work and then post the errors on [so]. You never know...

Comment: @DStanley At the very least you can just do `var foo = System.Web.HttpContext;` and then it will compile so you can debug and inspect.

Comment: its asp.net,and it is a .net Standard

Comment: Why did you make it a .NET Standard library? If you have no particular reason, then perhaps you should convert it to a .NET Framework class library. Or just don't consume HttpContext from your .NET Standard library.

Comment: Duplicate of [HttpContext in .net standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47357689/1260204)