# IResult (from Asp) not found in standard 2.0 project

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I created a DLL project targeting .net standard 2.0.

With NuGet I added a reference to Microfosft.AspNetCore.Http. (2.2.2)

I created this class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace netstdlib
{
   public class Class1
   {
      public IResult DoGet()
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
}
```

When I build I get

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: netstdlib, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>D:\PROJECTS\experiment\CS framework test\netstdlib\Class1.cs(10,25,10,32): error CS0246: 
  The type or namespace name 'IResult' could not be found (are you missing a using 
  directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Done building project "netstdlib.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It seems to me it should find IResult in the library I'm using.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Camilo for pointing out why IResult can't work.  I did find a way that will work:

HttpResponseMessage as produced by HttpClient.GetAsync is usable in .net core.  Whether or not these classes are usable in .net framework I didn't try, but I can use HttpResponseMessage to extract data in a Standard dll, and return that data to a .net framework project.

Answer (score 3):

The `IResult` interface in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace was added in ASP.NET Core 6, so you need to update if you want to use it.

See documentation: [IResult Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: This is not a question of Update.  Standard is required for a library that's used by both Framework and Core.  I need an alternative.

Comment: never head of IActionResult.  I assumed there was something pre-6 but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Trying to learn the framework to build a library that provides app-specific HTTP services that is consumable by Framework and Core environments.  I only started working Http with .net6 and I needed to make some code available to a .net framework project.

Comment: Then you should be interested in knowing that there is **no way** to share HTTP methods between ASP.NET Framework and ASP.NET Core - read on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357689/httpcontext-in-net-standard-library/47357919#47357919

Comment: Oh thank you very much for that pointer.  That is a huge change in direction for me.