# How do I get full URL of a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to get the full URL of a page using C# Razor code (ex: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`).

When I tried looking up how to do this, everyone has access to `Request.Url`, `HttpContent.Current.Request`, or something similar. However, these are not available to me (I'm assuming becuase I am using .NET Core, not sure).

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574489/84206

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access the current HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @JuanR It's weird to need that in ASP.NET Core. You should first ask where the OP is attempting to get the URL before blindly injecting that accessor

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The full URL is at best a reconstruction, it's not transmitted like that in the request. You also need to consider the encoding.

Comment: Are you trying to get the URL of *current* page, or *another* page?

Comment: @NightOwl888 The current page.