# Net Core: 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current'`

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0

I am migrating a project from .Net 4.6.2 into .Net Core 2.0.
I am receiving error below. `'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current'`

How would I resolve this?

**Original Code:**

```
public class CustomerAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// Gets or sets a session variable indicates that the logged in user has been already authorized to login to the system. 
    private bool IsAuthorized
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAuthorized"] != null &&
```

**Error Code:**

```
'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current'
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
public class CustomerAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // Gets or sets a session variable indicates that the logged in user has been already authorized to login to the system. 

    const string IsAuthorized2 = "IsAuthorized";
    private bool IsAuthorized
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString(IsAuthorized2) != null
```

**Error:**

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Also see: [Access the current HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: Here's a great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574489/3883866

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access the current HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Might want to take a look at the SessionStorage object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: hmm, this is not working, is there another solution?

Comment: @JohnThomas You need to post your own question instead of adding a bounty to a question with an accepted answer. Apparently the accepted answer worked for OP, you're not going to get more/different answers here unless you post *why* this doesn't work for you.