# Cannot use HttpContext.Session in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I've added `app.UseSession();` to my startup.Configure and `services.AddSession()` to my ConfigureServices.

Now if I try to use Session like this:

`HttpContext.Session.SetString("Type", tableName);`

I get "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property, 'HttpContext.Session'"

However, if I try to instantiate it like this:
`HttpContext context = new HttpContext();`

it says: "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'HttpContext"

How can I access session?

**IQuery.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace AppName.Services
{
    public interface IQuery
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetListOfDatabases(string dbName);
    }
    public class InMemoryIquery : IQuery
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetListOfDatabases(string tableName)
        {
        if(tableName != null)
            {
               HttpContext.Session.SetString("Type", tableName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what context are you accessing it? See [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I am trying to access it from within a class that inherits an interface

Comment: Can you post the full code where you are trying to access the Session?

Comment: We can help, if you send the full code of that class that accesses the session.

Comment: I've posted the code above. Thanks

Comment: As the docs say _"t's only necessary to use IHttpContextAccessor **when you need access to the HttpContext inside a service**."_ And it looks from your code that that is the case.

Comment: .. so see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) about how to register and use the accessor

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class add the `IHttpContextAccessor` to your constructor and use like this

```
public class InMemoryIquery : IQuery
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public InMemoryIquerty(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetListOfDatabases(string tableName)
    {
    if(tableName != null)
        {
           _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("CalculationType", tableName);
        }
    }
}
```

In your ConfigureServices add the following line `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` after `services.AddControllersWithViews();`

Answer (score -1):

In the outside of this class, Use this to get current HttpContext.

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
```

Then inject it into the constructor of this class. you must have something like this:

```
public InMemoryIquery(HttpContext httpContext)
{
   httpContext.Session.SetString("CalculationType", tableName);
}
```

Comment: This is not correct in .Net Core, or possibly anywhere. You should use the `HttpContextAccessor`

Comment: oh you right in.net core, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core