# ASP.NET Core 6: problems with HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cookies, httpcontext

I wrote the following public method:

```
 public IList<CookieType> GetAcceptedCookieTypes(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var result = new List<CookieType>();
            // accepted by default
            result.Add(CookieType.Essential);

            var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies["cc_cookie_accept"];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                var arrVal = cookie.Split('.');
                if (arrVal != null && arrVal.Length > 1)
                {
                    var arrCheck = arrVal[1];
                    if (arrCheck.Length > 0 && arrCheck[0] == '1')
                    {
                        result.Add(CookieType.Statistical);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I have multiple places where the method gets consumed, but I keep getting this error since I had to add the `HttpContext httpContext`:

`Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'httpContext' of 'GDPRScript.GetAcceptedCookieTypes(HttpContext)`

I tried consuming it like this:

```
var _httpContext = HttpContext httpContext;
types = GetAcceptedCookieTypes(_httpContext);
```

But then it throws 3 errors on the definition of _httpContext (value) them being:
CS0103, CS0201, CS1002

- How can I properly fix this?

Comment: `var _httpContext = (HttpContext) httpContext;`?

Comment: @vernou then it apparently complains about the `httpContext` not existing in the current context

Comment: Where do you call this method? From a derived `ControllerBase`?

Comment: @vernou I think I call it from a custom component, how can I check/determine?

Comment: What is the class where is problematic code?

Comment: Maybe this other question can help : [Access the current HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: The combination of the suggested question and the answer below made the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the HttpContext that is... well, in your *context*. Since you did not explain what your context of calling this method is, you will need to find that yourself:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0

In this link, there is a list how to get your HttpContext depending on what technology you use. ASP.NET Core is a wide field of technologies or ways to call or be called and the way to get a HttpContext varies slightly in each.

If you are not directly calling this in your controller, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#access-httpcontext-from-custom-components) might be your way of getting a HttpContext via Dependency injection in any component.

Comment: I extended my startup.cs with this: `services.AddControllers();
            // TEST add HttpContext functionality globally
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` but apparently it still throws the same error...

Comment: Uh, yes, you have to follow the instructions, *all* of them. Did you inject a `IHttpContextAccessor` into your class and use `injectedVariable.HttpContext`?

Comment: Works wonders! Thanks!