# Use HttpContext in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net

in .net 4.6.2 we are using HttpContext like this

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("language", languageCode);
```

But the same is faling in .net 5 and 6  What is the alternative for the above code.

Comment: Why are you adding headers to the current request? What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-the-current-httpcontext-in-asp-net-core) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571032/how-to-get-httpcontext-current-in-asp-net-core).
You can access the current request from the property `HttpContext` from within a controller or inject `IHttpContextAccessor` anywhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add from client side:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = uri };

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("language", "en");
```

Comment: What  is the uri value here