# Setting innerText of href element in c# using content starts with ~/

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, href, asp.net-4.5

I have a web application in asp.net/c# 4.5

I have an `href` element on my front-end like below:

```
<a href="" id="myhref" runat="server"> my text </a>
```

What I want is to set an href and innerText to the element using c#, but the content will be starting with ~/

So in the code what I do:

```
myhref.href = "~/default.aspx?id=" + ID;
myhref.InnerText= "~/default.aspx?id=" + ID;
```

The problem is even though `href` looks like `"http://localhost:12345/default.aspx?id=10"` and once clicked it navigates the user to the correct page, the inner text on the screen is `"~/default.aspx?id=10"`. I need the `innerText` to show the complete address on the screen as well. How can I provide it?

Thanks

Comment: maybe see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189953/how-to-get-current-domain-name-in-asp-net/26190007

Answer (score 0):

Check this post out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214619/15082946

Hopefully that will help you :)

```
using System.Web;

Uri MyUrl = Request.Url; <----
 Response.Write("URL Port: " + MyUrl.Port + "<br>");
```